# ¿Como contar objetos creados?

Tags: java, poo

como puedo contar los estudiantes dentro de cada curso que tengo creado, no necesito contar el total de estudiantes creados, necesito saber el total de estudiantes por cada curso y saber cual es el curso que mas estudiantes tiene

```
        
        Curso curso1 = new Curso("LP001","Lenguajes de Programacion","2404","Miércoles",3,17,3);
        curso1.matricularEstudiante(estudiante1);
        numPersonas1++;
        curso1.matricularEstudiante(estudiante2);
        numPersonas1++;
        curso1.matricularEstudiante(estudiante3);
        numPersonas1++;
        curso1.matricularEstudiante(estudiante4);
        numPersonas1++;
        
        
        Curso curso2 = new Curso("SO001","Sistemas Operativos","2403","Jueves",4,15,3);
        curso2.matricularEstudiante(estudiante5);
        curso2.matricularEstudiante(estudiante6);
        curso2.matricularEstudiante(estudiante7);
        
        
        Curso curso3 = new Curso("PDA01","Python para desarrolo web","2402","viernes",4,16,3);
        curso3.matricularEstudiante(estudiante8);
        curso3.matricularEstudiante(estudiante9);
```

Comment: Te respondí aunque no debí de haberlo hecho, para la siguiente asegúrate de incluir más detalles para hacer más sencilla tu pregunta, por ejemplo, el código de la clase **Curso** y el de la clase **Estudiante** o si es en realidad un String. Por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la interfaz [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) para poder usar fácilmente [Collections#max](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)).

La interfaz Comparable debería de comparar en este caso el número de alumnos inscritos, por ejemplo, comparando el tamaño de la lista de alumnos.

Además, te recomiendo guardar tus cursos en una lista o un vector para no estar creando tantas y tantas variables.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student student1 = new Student("Pedro", "Salazar", "M456FG");
        Student student2 = new Student("Marta", "Salazar", "F766JK");
        Student student3 = new Student("Sandra", "Salazar", "F006TH");
        Student student4 = new Student("Paola", "Salazar", "F456FG");
        Student student5 = new Student("Bernardo", "Salazar", "M876RN");

        List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>(3);

        courses.add(new Course("Lenguas extranjeras", "RT5643G"));
        courses.add(new Course("Sistemas operativos", "REF56HD"));
        courses.add(new Course("Sistemas digitales", "GYH72FN"));

        courses.get(0).addStudent(student1);
        courses.get(0).addStudent(student2);
        courses.get(0).addStudent(student3);

        courses.get(1).addStudent(student4);
        courses.get(1).addStudent(student5);

        courses.get(2).addStudent(student1);
        courses.get(2).addStudent(student3);
        courses.get(2).addStudent(student4);
        courses.get(2).addStudent(student5);



        System.out.println("Curso con más inscritos" + Collections.max(courses));
        System.out.println("**************************************************");
        courses.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("**************************************************");

    }

    private static class Student {
        private String name;
        private String lastname;
        private String id;

        public Student(String name, String lastname, String id) {
            this.name = name;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    private static class Course implements Comparable<Course> {
        private String name;
        private String id;
        private List<Student> students;

        public Course(String name, String id) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
            this.students = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        protected void addStudent(Student student) {
            students.add(student);
        }

        protected int getEnrolledCount() {
            return students.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Course o) {
            return Integer.compare(getEnrolledCount(), o.getEnrolledCount());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Curso: ".concat(name).concat("\tInscritos: ") + getEnrolledCount();
        }
    }
}
```

Este código te va a devolver el primer elemento que tenga más elementos, es decir, si dos cursos tienen el mismo número de alumnos inscritos y son máximos, entonces devuelve sólo uno. Para imprimir todos, deberías de obtener el máximo y luego imprimir todos aquellos que tengan el mismo número, para ello puedes hacer un sort con [Collections#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

Si no quieres implementar Comparable, igual puedes hacer uso de [List#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) ayudándote de la clase [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html)

```java
courses.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Course::getEnrolledCount).reversed());

System.out.println("Curso con más inscritos" + courses.get(0));
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es muy probable que no responda a la pregunta, para empezar porque los objetos `Curso` de la pregunta y tu objeto `Course` no se parecen absolutamente en nada. Su objeto tiene 7 parámetros de los cuales no sabemos absolutamente nada acerca de ellos. Cómo puedes desarrollar una solución basándote en datos inventados por ti mismo? En caso de duda, lo correcto es añadir un comentario solicitando una explicación/más información, no inventarnos una respuesta. Dado que es obviamente un ejercicio de clase, es incluso probable que no pueda implementar la interfaz mencionada...

Comment: El principio es lo mismo. Al final de cuentas, ¿Qué de relevancia tienen los otros datos para la comparación que quiere? ¿Cómo influyen esos parámetros en el número de alumnos inscritos?

Comment: @Benito-B Esta respuesta aunque no tiene la misma clase curso, tiene una propuesta de solución que posiblemente ayudará a la autora y a los futuros lectores con el problema de raíz

Comment: No solo los parámetros, me refiero al hecho en si mismo de que no conoces la implementación de su clase. Ni sabes nada del contexto del autor. Repito, la pregunta es obviamente un ejercicio de clase, seguramente esté todavía aprendiendo a manejar objetos y tú le estás metiendo interfaces, method references y *"cosas raras"* (`courses.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Course::getEnrolledCount).reversed());`, esto para alguien que esté aprendiendo java no le sirve de nada... y menos en clase, es obvio que lo copiarán y pegarán sin aprender nada). Lo mejor habría sido pedir que aclare su pregunta.

Comment: De todas maneras tú mismo lo has dicho en tu comentario en su pregunta, *Te respondí aunque no debí de haberlo hecho*

Comment: @Benito-B Más que nada, las respuestas que escribo trato de hacerlas lo mejor posible, para que personas que en un futuro tengan la misma duda y tengan los conocimientos suficientes puedan usarla como referencia. Además trato de hacerlas lo más explicativas que puedo y aunque luego se me olvida, suelo comentar (si es el caso) que espero que la respuesta aunque complicada para quien preguntó sea algo que lo impulse a investigar más estos temas para que mejore sus habilidades y aprenda otras formas más "correctas" de solucionar los problemas

Comment: En cualquier caso la respuesta da una solución viable, no dice incoherencias y tiene enlaces a la documentación oficial (que está súper bien explicada para entender el uso correcto) para que pueda estudiar lo que menciono. ¿Aún así te parece tan mala respuesta?